# PHP & strtotime headache

Tags: php, strtotime

Here's my function

```
function thisProduction($week_start, $week_end, $this){
echo "<h2>Production > $this week (w/c ".$week_start." - ".$week_end.")</h2>";
}
```

Here's where I define the args

```
$this_week_start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this Monday'));
$this_week_end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('this Sunday'));
$last_week_start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Monday'));
$last_week_end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('last Sunday'));
```

I call this will arguments as such

```
thisProduction($this_week_start, $this_week_end, 'This');
thisProduction($last_week_start, $last_week_end, 'Last');
```

**I WANT (using todays date 31 Jan 2017 as example)**

```
Production > This week (W/C 2017-01-30 - 2017-02-05)
Production > Last week (W/C 2017-01-23 - 2017-01-29)
```

Last night this was 'working' but today I get these results

```
PRODUCTION > THIS WEEK (W/C 2017-02-06 - 2017-02-05)
PRODUCTION > LAST WEEK (W/C 2017-01-30 - 2017-01-29)
```

Comment: `this Monday` means `coming Monday` if the current day is `not Monday`. so it is working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better use `monday this week`:

```
$this_week_start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('monday this week'));
$this_week_end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday this week'));
$last_week_start = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('monday last week'));
$last_week_end = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('sunday last week'));
```

Result today and yesterday:

Production > This week (w/c 2017-01-30 - 2017-02-05)

Production > Last week (w/c 2017-01-23 - 2017-01-29)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That's what I believed would work, too. But I run that, and get the same dates as in my post.  Perhaps it's a server setting PRODUCTION > THIS WEEK (W/C 2017-02-06 - 2017-02-05)
PRODUCTION > LAST WEEK (W/C 2017-01-30 - 2017-01-29)

Comment: @Brad Sullivan Check if `date('Y-m-d')` gives `2017-01-31`. I tested it and it works fine. local and onlinetester

Comment: Your code is perfect, thanks again. I agree it works on PHPTESTER as expected, but when on my hosting, i still get the same dates as in OP. Head. Wall.